# MSDeploy - possible to call setAcl on multiple destinations in one go?

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5, access-control-list, teamcity, msdeploy

I'm building a nice little continuous integration environment for our development team, based on TeamCity. It's working rather nicely, as it can build a mix of .NET and PHP projects, and push them to our internal and external platforms.

I'm primarily using MsDeploy to push everything to the internal platform, as that's all IIS based. However, there's a number of builds where I need to set directory permissions on the destination directory. I can use the `setAcl` operator just fine, but that only seems to take a single destination as an argument. Therefore, if I need to alter the permissions on 5 destination directories, I need to call MsDeploy 5 times, which seems a lot of overhead.

Is there a sensible way around this? Reading the documentation, I don't think MsDeploy takes more than a single argument for the `setAcl` operator, but could be wrong. Is there a better way for a build server to set multiple directory permissions in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`manifest` provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569104%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) is designed to sync multiple providers at one time:

```
msdeploy verb:sync -source:manifest=manifest.xml -dest:auto,computerName=...
```

Then `manifest.xml` is:

```
<multipleAcls>
    <setAcl path="path1" setAclAccess="Write" />
    <setAcl path="path2" setAclAccess="Read" />
    <setAcl path="path3" setAclAccess="ReadAndExecute" />
</multipleAcls>
```